# Method as property

Tags: .net, vb.net, webforms

I'm not really sure of the correct terminology here so my searches have been fruitless.

I have a class `MyClass` that has a `ToControls` function. This function returns  some custom controls.

When creating an instance of `MyClass` I wish to pass in a method that will be bound to the `OnClick` event of a `LinkButton` returned by `ToControls`.

Here is a simplified version:

```
Public Class MyClass

    Private proAction As Action

    Public Property Action() As Action
        Get
            Return proAction
        End Get
        Set(value As Action)
            proAction = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function ToControls() As Object
        Dim htmlWrapper As New HtmlGenericControl("div")

        Dim lnkTest As New LinkButton
        lnkTest.Text = "TEST"
        AddHandler lnkTest.Click, AddressOf Action.Method.Name
        ' ## Error: 'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses)

        htmlWrapper.Controls.Add(lnkTest)

        Return htmlWrapper
    End Function

End Class
```

My codebehind looks something like this:

```
Protected Sub MySub()
    Dim myObj As New MyClass
    myObj.Action = AddressOf MyPassedSub
End Sub

Protected Sub MyPassedSub()
    Response.Write("Hello World!")
End Sub
```

I've come across `Action` that I thought may be useable for this but I suspect that I am wrong.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Public Property CtrlEvent As EventHandler` should be all you need (auto implemented property).  for the class storage.  It really doesnt need to be a property but could just be a public member, or better still, unless you do want to get it and set it, pass the address of the handler in the constructor and store it as a private var.  You might want the `ToControl` method to return `Control` though

Comment: Hi @Plutonix. Thanks for your input. It's probably a problem with my implementation but I cant make that work. I've added `Public Property CtrlEvent As EventHandler` to `MyClass` and am now setting this from the code behind `objN.CtrlEvent = AddressOf NotificationAction`. This builds and runs but my Sub is not called when the LinkButton is clicked. I just get a postback. Any ideas?

Comment: when you create the control did you `AddHandler myObj.<EVENT NAME>, CtrlEvent`  the main thing wrong was the delegate handling.  make sure the event handler (SUB) signature is correct ( `sender As Object, e As EventArgs` )

Comment: I'm essentially doing this: https://gist.github.com/3rror404/7c2522dd927b679a609acc900a1e98e4. Does that look correct to you?

Comment: It looks *essentially* correct except your control factory only exists in `MySub` and nowhere in that scope do you call the `ToControl` method to create a control.  Otherwise that should work

Comment: Ah, yeah I missed a step there. I'm actually using a placeholder to output the controls `plhNotification.Controls.Add(objN.ToControls())`. Still I just get a postback when clicking the LinkButton.